# CreateProcess using netsh hangs/freezes the application [Delphi]

Tags: delphi, winapi, pascal

I'm using the code bellow to run a few "netsh wlan" commands in order to check wifi status, connect to a wifi profile, etc.

The problem that I'm having is that every now and then the app will hang on any of the commands, it's just a random thing, plus, sometimes the output returned get overwritten with "nothing", when I debugged it seemed like a timing issue.

I tried the conventional approach to run a command with Pascal but it didn't work with netsh, the approach is "cmd.exe /C netsh wlan....".

I appreciate any advise on getting this freezing procedure working better or another approach.

I'm running DelphiXE5.

Thanks

Sample commands: netsh wlan show profiles, netsh wlan show interfaces, etc.

```
procedure GetDosOutput(const ACommand, AParameters: String; CallBack: TArg<PAnsiChar>);
const
CReadBuffer = 2400;
var
saSecurity: TSecurityAttributes;
hRead: THandle;
hWrite: THandle;
suiStartup: TStartupInfo;
piProcess: TProcessInformation;
pBuffer: array [0 .. CReadBuffer] of AnsiChar;
dBuffer: array [0 .. CReadBuffer] of AnsiChar;
dRead: DWord;
dRunning: DWord;
begin
saSecurity.nLength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
saSecurity.bInheritHandle := True;
saSecurity.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;

if CreatePipe(hRead, hWrite, @saSecurity, 0) then
begin
    FillChar(suiStartup, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), #0);
    suiStartup.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
    suiStartup.hStdInput := hRead;
    suiStartup.hStdOutput := hWrite;
    suiStartup.hStdError := hWrite;
    suiStartup.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    suiStartup.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;

    if CreateProcess(nil, pChar(ACommand + ' ' + AParameters), @saSecurity, @saSecurity, True, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, suiStartup, piProcess) then
    begin
        repeat
            dRunning := WaitForSingleObject(piProcess.hProcess, 100);
            Application.ProcessMessages();
            repeat
                dRead := 0;
                ReadFile(hRead, pBuffer[0], CReadBuffer, dRead, nil);
                pBuffer[dRead] := #0;

                //OemToAnsi(pBuffer, pBuffer);
                //Unicode support by Lars Fosdal
                OemToCharA(pBuffer, dBuffer);
                CallBack(dBuffer);
            until (dRead < CReadBuffer);
        until (dRunning <> WAIT_TIMEOUT);
        CloseHandle(piProcess.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(piProcess.hThread);
    end;
    CloseHandle(hRead);
    CloseHandle(hWrite);
end;
end;
```

**After following all the advises I got this portion of code changed and so far the app hasn't hanged anymore.
Thanks a lot!**

```
procedure GetDosOutput(const ACommand, AParameters: String; CallBack: TArg<PAnsiChar>);
const
CReadBuffer = 2400;
var
saSecurity: TSecurityAttributes;
hRead: THandle;
hWrite: THandle;
suiStartup: TStartupInfo;
piProcess: TProcessInformation;
pBuffer: array [0 .. CReadBuffer] of AnsiChar;
dBuffer: array [0 .. CReadBuffer] of AnsiChar;
dRead: DWord;
dRunning: DWord;
begin
saSecurity.nLength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
saSecurity.bInheritHandle := True;
saSecurity.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;

if CreatePipe(hRead, hWrite, @saSecurity, 0) then
begin
    FillChar(suiStartup, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), #0);
    suiStartup.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
    suiStartup.hStdInput := hRead;
    suiStartup.hStdOutput := hWrite;
    suiStartup.hStdError := hWrite;
    suiStartup.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    suiStartup.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;

    if CreateProcess(nil, pChar(ACommand + ' ' + AParameters), @saSecurity, @saSecurity, True, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, suiStartup, piProcess) then
    begin
        Application.ProcessMessages();
        repeat
            dRunning := WaitForSingleObject(piProcess.hProcess, 100);

            repeat
                dRead := 0;

                try
                  ReadFile(hRead, pBuffer[0], CReadBuffer, dRead, nil);
                except on E: Exception do
                  Exit;
                end;

                pBuffer[dRead] := #0;

                //OemToAnsi(pBuffer, pBuffer);
                //Unicode support by Lars Fosdal
                OemToCharA(pBuffer, dBuffer);
                CallBack(dBuffer);
            until (dRead < CReadBuffer);

        until (dRunning <> WAIT_TIMEOUT);
        CloseHandle(piProcess.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(piProcess.hThread);
    end;
    CloseHandle(hRead);
    CloseHandle(hWrite);
end;
end;
```

**I created this wrapper to simplify the process:**

```
function GetDosOutputSimple(const ACommand, AParameters: String) : String;
var
  Tmp, S : String;
begin
  GetDosOutput(ACommand, AParameters, procedure (const Line: PAnsiChar)
  begin
    Tmp := Line;
    S := S + Tmp;
  end);

  GetDosOutputSimple := S;
end;
```

Comment: You are not checking for errors. Hard to see past that. Why would you call Win32 functions, have problems, and just ignore error checking?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write this, if you could post any improvement that would be great.

Comment: @David - That would only lead to a better description of the problem in this case though, since this is about an api not returning.

Comment: You need to learn how to check for errors. And avoid giving child processes all of your handles. Read the docs.

Comment: @paul - re (edit): where are you closing the handles now?

Comment: I haven't changed that portion, after the first repeat/until I close the process and thread, and after the last repeat/until I close  the hRead and hWrite.

Comment: @paul - Well, then i suspect you haven't fixed your code yet, as you're not waiting for the process either.

Comment: Could you please post the complete code with your suggestion?

Comment: @paul - The last modification of the answer contains the complete GetDosOutput - except the variables (just declare a DWORD 'flags') and the 'begin' and 'end'. Give that a try..  Also use '@' and account name so the person you commented gets notified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for any reason by the time you call `ReadFile`, the process have not completed a write operation, or your buffer is not filled, `ReadFile` will block. Normally it should fail, but it can't since you're holding a handle to the write end. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa365782%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> ... It is important for the parent process to close its handle to the
>   write end of the pipe before calling **ReadFile**. If this is not done,
>   the **ReadFile** operation cannot return zero because the parent process
>   has an open handle to the write end of the pipe.

So close 'hWrite' before reading from the pipe.

Note that, in this case - if the process have not been able to write anything to the pipe yet, instead of blocking, [`ReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will properly fail - and `GetLastError` will report `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE`. Under this condition, you'd probably gracefully fail too. So better check return of `ReadFile`.

Alternatively, wait until the process terminates. Then you won't risk `ReadFile` blocking waiting for writing since the handles on child's side will have been closed.

```
    ...
repeat
    dRunning := WaitForSingleObject(piProcess.hProcess, 100);
    Application.ProcessMessages();
until (dRunning <> WAIT_TIMEOUT);
repeat
    dRead := 0;
    ...
```

If there's a chance that you'll have some sizeable output, read from the pipe when the application is running:

```
  saSecurity.nLength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
  saSecurity.bInheritHandle := True;
  saSecurity.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;

  if CreatePipe(hRead, hWrite, @saSecurity, 0) then begin
    try
      FillChar(suiStartup, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), #0);
      suiStartup.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
      suiStartup.hStdInput := hRead;
      suiStartup.hStdOutput := hWrite;
      suiStartup.hStdError := hWrite;
      suiStartup.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
      suiStartup.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;

      if CreateProcess(nil, pChar(ACommand + ' ' + AParameters), @saSecurity,
                      @saSecurity, True, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil,
                      suiStartup, piProcess) then begin
        CloseHandle(hWrite);
        try
          repeat
            dRunning := WaitForSingleObject(piProcess.hProcess, 100);
            Application.ProcessMessages();

            repeat
              dRead := 0;
              if ReadFile(hRead, pBuffer[0], CReadBuffer, dRead, nil) then begin
                pBuffer[dRead] := #0;
                OemToCharA(pBuffer, dBuffer);
                CallBack(dBuffer);
              end;
            until (dRead < CReadBuffer);

          until (dRunning <> WAIT_TIMEOUT);
        finally
          CloseHandle(piProcess.hProcess);
          CloseHandle(piProcess.hThread);
        end;

      end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(hRead);
      if GetHandleInformation(hWrite, flags) then
        CloseHandle(hWrite);
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Guys, I'm not really good at this API stuff and this is totally copied from the internet, don't remember where I got it.
I will try to do the change as suggested but if you could post any improvement here I would appreciate.

Comment: @paul - In that case, if you don't understand what your code is doing, your best bet could be waiting till the process terminates and reading from the pipe then. Move the outer `until` to after `Application.ProcessMessages`. And I believe you can check the return of `ReadFile` and exit if anything goes wrong yourself.