# How to use `TArg<PAnsiChar>` in delphi?

Tags: delphi, createprocess

how does one use `TArg<PAnsiChar>`?

The compiler saies it would be undefined.

Do I need to include something, install something or what do I need? 
After google search I only found the Spring Framework for Delphi. I am not quite sure whether that's what is needed to be able to use `<TArg<PAnsiChar>`. I am using Delphi Starter 10.2.

I'm thankful for any help on this...

---

**Update from comments:**

The expression `TArg<PAnsiChar>` is used in this question:

[CreateProcess using netsh hangs/freezes the application [Delphi]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20712386/576719)

```
procedure GetDosOutput(const ACommand, AParameters: String; CallBack: TArg<PAnsiChar>);
```

Comment: If the compiler does not find the declaration, add the declaration or the unit it is declared in. After that it would be possible to use it. If you don't know what it is or where the expression comes from, what is the purpose of using it?

Comment: BTW, the Spring4D `TArg` is a record with generic methods, like `TArg.Isxxx<T>`, which differs from what's in the question.

Comment: You really need to tell us what you think this `TArg` is. The compiler message is pretty clear isn't it.

Comment: Show us some context. How are you trying to use it, and why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712386/createprocess-using-netsh-hangs-freezes-the-application-delphi

procedure GetDosOutput(const ACommand, AParameters: String; CallBack: TArg<PAnsiChar>);

Comment: Please remove this question. It cannot. Be answered. Or, fix it to provide the missing information.

Answer (score 0):

From the linked question one can see that the `TArg<PAnsiChar>` is used as a callback parameter:

```
procedure GetDosOutput(const ACommand, AParameters: String; CallBack: TArg<PAnsiChar>);
```

It is used in a call as an anonymous procedure:

```
GetDosOutput(ACommand, AParameters, 
  procedure (const Line: PAnsiChar)
  begin
    Tmp := Line;
    S := S + Tmp;
  end
);
```

This implies that the declaration of `TArg<PAnsiChar>` should look like:

```
type
  TArg<T> = reference to procedure (const Arg1: T);
```